# Condition inside the datatabele

Tags: javascript, if-statement, datatable, conditional-statements

I created data table and in this, I want to check the condition, here is the part of my code:

```
buttons: [
                {
                    extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                    exportOptions: {
                    if(group_id != topManagementUserLevel){
                        columns: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
                          }
                    }
                },
            ],
```

I want to add if condition to check some values but when I am inserted that one into code Its gives an error.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token !=
```

Is there a any other way to do this

Comment: You want `columns` in `exportOptions` if `group_id != topManagementUserLevel`?

Comment: Try something like using ternary operator - `columns: (group_id != topManagementUserLevel) ? [0, 1, 2, 3, 4] : []`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `ternary operator` instead of `if`.

```js
const group_id = 1;
const topManagementUserLevel = 2;

buttons = [
    {
        extend: 'pdfHtml5',
        exportOptions: {
            columns: (group_id != topManagementUserLevel) ? [0, 1, 2, 3, 4] : []
        }
    },
];

console.log(buttons);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this conditional statement.

```
columns: (group_id != topManagementUserLevel) ? [0, 1, 2, 3, 4] : undefined
```